# Configuration classes from appsettings.json

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to build the classes for my configuration to be loaded from appsettings.json.

This is the appsettings.json section I'm having issue with. I cannot figure out how to build the object for the ConnectionStrings.
The example below doesn't allow more than one connection string and we don't want to "name" the property based on the connection 
string name in the appsettings.json.

I understand that we may need to change the code that references the connection string to read this object differently than we currently do.

Anyone have an easy way to do this?

**appsettings.json**

```
"ModuleConfig": {
    "IpAddress": "The IP",
    "Port": "The Module Port",
    "Buffer": "1024",
    "ConnectionStrings": {        
        "OracleKeyManagement": "The Connection string"
    },
    "Redis": {
        "Host": "localhost",
        "Port": "The Redis Port"
    }
}
```

**Configuration classes - UPDATED**

```
public class ModuleConfig
{
    IpAddress { get; set; } = "The IP",
    Port { get; set; } = "The Module Port",
    Buffer { get; set; } = "1024",
    public Dictionary<string,string> ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
    public RedisConfig RedisConfig { get; set; } 
}

public class ConnStrings
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> ConnectionStrings { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, string>() {{"OracleKeyManagement","The Connection String"}};
};

public class Redis 
{
    public string Host { get; set; } = "localhost";
    public string Port { get; set; } = "The Redis Port";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simply using Dictionary Class? like:

```
public class ModuleConfig
{
    IpAddress { get; set; } = "The IP",
    Port { get; set; } = "The Module Port",
    Buffer { get; set; } = "1024",
    public Dictionary<string, string> ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
    public Redis RedisConfig { get; set } 
}
```